# How can I enlarge an image for Android without blurring it?

Tags: android, image, size

I use Eclipse and it makes a blurred image.

This image shows what I want:

[image]

Comment: By blurry do you mean pixelated? If so you can't really make it bigger without a higher quality/resolution source image.

Comment: I dont want blurry image, I want like this image, pixelated. Yes, I want it pixelated but eclipse make it so blurred :s

Comment: You should use a low resolution image

Comment: See this image pls http://i.gyazo.com/dc70032c0e2c5dbf0372e002197d25f3.png

Comment: what do you mean `Eclipse make`? eclipse does not include an image resize tool that I know of.

Comment: That is true. But I'm not English and I can not explain it better ... Do anyone know what I show in the picture, or they will be aware of the way you say ... I think it is well understood ...

Comment: please tell me if you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really enough context given for me to provide a solution, but at the very least I can guess.

You want to load the image in a `Drawable` and call `setFilterBitmap(false)` before setting it to an `ImageView`.

A brief example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private Drawable smallResource;

private ImageView resourceImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    resourceImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_resource);

    smallResource = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.small_resource);
    smallResource.setFilterBitmap(false);

    resourceImageView.setImageDrawable(smallResource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the image size and keep the imageview size fixed

Comment: I want increase the image. See this pic please http://i.gyazo.com/dc70032c0e2c5dbf0372e002197d25f3.png

Comment: Try putting the image in /res/raw and see if it helps ..resources in raw folder wont be optimized or process..refer-http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/27/using-files-as-raw-resources-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Its Eclipse good quality that it is not making pixeled image.

Comment: But I want it pixelated. How can I do that. See this pic http://i.gyazo.com/dc70032c0e2c5dbf0372e002197d25f3.png

Answer (score 0):

http://postimg.org/image/zaio51pr1/

I have enlarged it to a very large size and then reduced and sharpened the image using Photoshop.This is a simple trick called Supersampling

See if adding this in eclipse helps.

Contact me if u want an even higher resolution version , I'll mail you one

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Photoshop, here's how I do it to preserve the hard edge and 
still look pixelated.

-Open the desired image in Photoshop
-save as a copy and choose as a bitmap : .pbm file
-now open the new .pbm file you just saved and select image size and change the image size there with preserve hard edges option.

If you don't have Photoshop, you can still do it with paint
-Open your image, save as-> choose .bmp
-then open the .bmp file you created, choose image size and resize the image

difference is the Photoshop is better to preserve the hard edges because they have a better interpretation. But paint is still good to get the job done, I had enlarge a 32*32 picture to 900*900 and still look pretty good.